# Angularjs: Function to return data back to html

Tags: html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have this weird problem that I expected to work but dose not.

In my template I'm using a table with a function call to retrieve a users name and display that data instead of the id of the user. I've tested the function by itself without using a html sided call and only in java script and it works. But I wonder why it won't return data back to the html side.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Users = [{
    "id": 1,
    "display_name": "John Deer",
    "role_id": 1,
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "display_name": "Julie Deer",
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "display_name": "John Smith",
  }];
  $scope.Departments = [{
    "id": 1,
    "created_by_id": 1,
    "last_modified_by_id": 2,
    "name": "Administrators",
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "created_by_id": 2,
    "last_modified_by_id": 1,
    "name": "Guest"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "created_by_id": 1,
    "last_modified_by_id": 2,
    "name": "Manager"
  }];

  $scope.getUserByID = function(ID) {
    console.log('Running getUserByID with: ' + ID + ', as the ID.')
    angular.forEach($scope.Users, function(item, index) {
      if (ID == item.id) {
        console.log('Match is ' + this.Users[index].display_name);
        return this.Users[index].display_name;
      }
    }, $scope);
  }
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

.well {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <div class="container col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="filterDepartments" value="Search" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Type here to search in the list." placeholder="Search Here">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 well">
    <h3>Departments</h3>
    <table id="example" class="display table" style="width: 100%; cellspacing: 0;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Created By</th>
          <th>Modified By</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Created By</th>
          <th>Modified By</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="y in Departments|filter:filterDepartments">
          <td>{{y.id}}</td>
          <td>{{y.name}}</td>
          <td>{{getUserByID(y.created_by_id)}}</td>
          <td>{{y.last_modified_by_id}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 panel">
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 well">
    <h3>Users</h3>
    <table id="example" class="display table" style="width: 100%; cellspacing: 0;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in Users">
          <td>{{x.id}}</td>
          <td>{{x.display_name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I made a plunk for you to play with: https://embed.plnkr.co/WUBKSD4pBxJnzc9ntUuO/

Let me know what you think as I am trying to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: any specific reason for two column headings -           <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>

Comment: @Naga Sai A - It's a header and a footer. I like the this format with long lists where much data could be confusing the tired eyes. It's really just a preference that I always do . I hope doing this help those who may get lost lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of changes to $scope.getUserByID.

One is that you can simply use the item object directly to get the display_name property from it.

The other issue is that putting a return in an angular.forEach does not break the loop so you just need to set a local var (userName) to the name initially that can be checked for a value and ultimately set as the return value.

```
$scope.getUserByID = function(ID) {
  console.log('Running getUserByID with: ' + ID + ', as the ID.')
  var userName;
  angular.forEach($scope.Users, function(item, index) {
    if (!userName) {
      if (ID == item.id) {
        userName = item.display_name;
        console.log('Match is ' + userName);
      }
    }
  }, $scope);

  return userName;
}
```

I've forked your [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/PM05MpTjbPfWRppLY07N?p=preview) with it working.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for explaining my problem. :D

Answer (score 1):

To achieve, expeccted result, change ng-repeat to below

Option-1: to work with existing getUserByID function, move the return value out of foreach loop

```
  $scope.getUserByID = function(ID) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log('Running getUserByID with: ' + ID + ', as the ID.')
    angular.forEach($scope.Users, function(item, index) {
      if (ID == item.id) {
        x = this.Users[index].display_name;
        console.log('Match is ' + this.Users[index].display_name);

      }
    }, $scope);
    return x
  }
```

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/grxKrK

Option-2- Avoid getUserById option and using Users object

```
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="y in Departments|filter:filterDepartments">
      <td>{{y.id}}</td>
      <td>{{y.name}}</td>
      <td>{{Users[y.created_by_id].display_name}}</td>
      <td>{{y.last_modified_by_id}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/AXoaGB

Getting User name by id , using Users[].required field name {{Users[y.created_by_id].display_name}}

Using above mentioned logic, will avoid writing additional function to getUserByID

Comment: This would work great if the index of Users matched the id values from individual users. Maybe there is a way to get the Object index to match those record ids

Comment: if user is not available, do you want to display blank ??

Comment: are you trying to set any default value, if there is no user with id in Users?

Comment: @ Naga Sai A - my project dosn't really account for a no user record problem. everything should be accounted for as far as data is concerned. So to answer that question, it would have to be blank.

Comment: @AochiToxx i have updated codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OXjEJE with the additional user in the Users object and invalid in the created_by_id in Departments object..Hope this works for you :)

Comment: I gave created_by_id value to 5 which is not having match in the Users object ,so that is getting displayed blank and added additional user with id-7

Comment: haha this would work great if the id value matched the users index value. In my main application the Object Users is just filled with users. so for exsample: Users[3] could contain this {
    "id": 1,
    "display_name": "John Deer",
    "role_id": 1,
  }

so this would return the wrong user based on useing the index instead of the user id.

Comment: @AochiToxx, Updated post with same logic what you have used and http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/grxKrK

Comment: @AochiToxx just moved the return statement out of ForEach loop ...Hope this works for you :)